# Best (safest) way to connect Android App to an online database

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite

I will need to connect my Android App (which is being programmed on Android Studio) to a database. What I don't know, and Google is not giving any good answers, is how should I connect this App to a database. I'm looking for a safe way of receiving and sending data.
The options I know are: MySQL database, REST database and SQLite (but SQLite is an offline database, so it is not what I'm looking for).

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "but SQLite is an offline database" ?? Please explain this (in my opinion) false statement.

Comment: "REST database" Please explain what you do mean by that sort of database...

Comment: Maybe you have to re-do you definition of database...

Comment: I really wonder why the `sqlite` tag was removed....

Answer (score 0):

There are many online database that are 'safe' to connect to, MongoDB, Azure, AWS, Firebase, Oracle databases etc. The best one will depend on which bests suits your application. And all these are safe at least to the extent that depends on the providers, you also need to make sure your implementation is safe and best.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the data transfer between an android application and any relational database is done using [api](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API). The api can be written using any server side languages like php, java, javascript using node, python etc. You can also connect to firebase firestore or other non relational databases. The choice is yours. For example, if your system is mainly doing read action and not that much write action then you can go with non relational database like MongoDB. If it has a lot of write action then choosing relational database like MySQL, PostgreSQL will be good.